# JS select all anchor elements inside a table

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, target

I have an html page with a section with a table. It consist of links and i need to get them all, preferably in some sort of an array. When I try to target a single link in the table, it works, i just copy the JS path and it works. But i cant target all the links in the table no matter what I do, it often returns null or gives an error. Here is the path to a single rown in a table, this works, but i need all the a hrefs inside the table, pls help!

```
#anchor-text-chart-section > div.table-container.mob-single-panel > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.anchorText > a
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML we cannot reproduce this.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#anchor-text-chart-section table a');`

Comment: It returns [object object]. cant it be that the element is not there/generated?

Comment: I'm using my employers accout to majestic.com, i can screenshot or copy paste the html, would that be enough?

Comment: https://imgur.com/mSBOB4K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#anchor-text-chart-section table a');
const urls = [];
for (const element of elements) {
  urls.push(element.href);
}
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: You should use `console.log` but not `return` in `Dev Tool`

Comment: You were right, it worked! Could you please explain?) I'm trying to do this with puppeteer, basically everything the same, but it doesn't work "(node:10168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: elements is not iterable"

Comment: `code` const elements = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('#anchor-text-chart-section table a'));
    


const urls = [];
      for (const element of elements) {
        urls.push(element.href);
      } return urls;
    console.log(urls);

Comment: `return` is to be used in `function`, I skipped it because I assume you would include it in a function

Comment: I do not know puppeteer, are you running the function after the DOM (content) is loaded?

Comment: yes. document.querySelector('#anchor-text-chart-section table a').innerText); returns what i need - a link converted to text.

Comment: but when i do 
document.querySelectorAll('#anchor-text-chart-section table a').innerText);

it returns undefined

Comment: No, `innerText` is actually no 'link converted to text'. It returns the rendered text in the element. `querySelector` returns the first matched element, `querySelectorAll` returns all matched elements in an array so you need to do loop.

Comment: get the elements, create a variable, iterate through the elements and add the a hrefs into a new var?

also could you please explain 

for (const element of elements)

what is the const element referring to?

Comment: Extremely, you can do without creating any variable. The key point is you need to access to the correct DOM element. `for (const element of elements)` is iteration value, [see more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)